# Total progeny of a population-dependent branching process

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, generating-functions

In a standard Galton-Watson process, you have the population in each generation given by $Z_n=\sum_{j=1}^{Z_{n-1}} X_j$. And the $X_j$s are all i.i.d. random variables. As far as I can tell, their i.i.d.-ness holds not just in a single generation but across all generations, so the $X_j$s in the 1000th generation are independent of those in the 10th generation, and distributed the same way. (Is that right?)

For that standard Galton-Watson process, the *total progeny* $T$ (total number of people who ever live from $n=0$ onwards) satisfies: $P(T=a | Z_0=b)=\frac{b}{a} P(Z_1 = a-b | Z_0=a)$.

Or, if we let $\varphi_{T}(s)$ be the probability generating function for $T$, and $\varphi$ be the p.g.f. for the distribution for each $X_j$, then $\varphi_{T}(s)=s \cdot \varphi (\varphi_{T}(s))$.

**But do both of those facts still hold if we let the $X_j$s have different distributions in each generation?** Specifically, if their distributions also depend on the size of the previous generation--if it's actually a *population-size-dependent* Galton-Watson process. For instance, the $X_j$s may have higher probability of returning 0 or 1 if the population is already very big. (This sort of process is discussed in [these](https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/3213745.pdf) [papers](https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/1427223.pdf), but they don't look at total progeny.)

I've gone through the proofs of both (the one from the original [Dwass](https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/3212112.pdf) paper for the first, and the basic proof by induction for the second) and I can't tell for sure whether they'd also work with the $X_j$ distributions being dependent on population size. (I realise that, for the second, $\varphi$ would have to be replaced with something like the limit of the offspring distribution as population size approaches 0 or $\infty$.) Do the results still hold?

Bonus question: are there any papers out there that talk about total progeny for population-size-dependent branching processes? I haven't had much luck finding any.

Comment: I think the upper limit of the sum is meant to be $Z_{n-1}$, not $Z_n-1$?

Comment: Yep, sorry, fixed now.